# ExoPlayer only using lowest rendition on HLS stream

Tags: exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I seem to be having an issue with ExoPlayer not wanting to use any higher renditions. The stream has 8 renditions, but ExoPlayer will only select the lowest using AdaptiveTrackSelection. When I manually set it to the 1080p rendition (using the TrackSelectionView dialog in ExoPlayer-UI), it runs fine.

Here is the code for the Player. I followed the demo. The stream works fine in the demo application.

```
open class VideoPlayer(val context: Context, val videoTitle: String) {
   val bandwidthMeter = DefaultBandwidthMeter()
   val videoTrackSelectionFactory = AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter)
   var trackSelector = DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory)
   var player: SimpleExoPlayer

   init {
       player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context, trackSelector)
   }

   fun setUrl(url: String, playWhenReady: Boolean = true) {
       player.playWhenReady = playWhenReady
       val mediaDataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(context, Util.getUserAgent(context, "Player"))
       val mediaSource = HlsMediaSource.Factory(mediaDataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(url))
       player.prepare(mediaSource)
   }

   fun releasePlayer() {
       player.release()
   }
}
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A silly mistake. Forgot to pass bandwithMeter in DefaultDataSourceFactory!